# Proper way to log Django User activity

Tags: python, django, django-models

What's the proper way to log user activity in Django?

For example let's say a user has `Groups`, and I'd like to keep a record of when `Object1` has been added or removed.

The method that comes to mind is to create a new record every time and pull the latest record but this feels wrong (and causes some filtering problems, eg: you can't just filter on `is_member=True` since you'll get stale results). Is there a proper way to log these in Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [django-auditable-models](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-auditable-models/1.0) for that. It will hook in the django workflow, and will avoid that you have to write all logic yourself.

Comment: There is no documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loggers in Django.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#topic-logging-parts-loggers

Answer (score 0):

To log something like that I recommend you to create an `core` app with a `TimeStampModel` model:

```python
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

class TimeStampModel(models.Model):
    """
    TimeStampModel class allows us to follow creation and update of each inherit instance
    """
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=now(), editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=now(), editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Now, inherit each models from `TimeStampModel` that you want to record creation or update date.

E.g:

```python
from django.db import models
from core.models import TimeStampModel

class Token(TimeStampModel):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    # ...
```

You can also add a `delete` attribute (Boolean) to realize logical delete. And the last update, will be the date of deletion.

**[Two Scoops of Django 1.8](http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-8) recommends also this practice.**